# Metadata-generation-failed when trying to install pygame

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pygame

Trying to install pygame on python 3.11 using the following command "pip install pygame" and I am getting the following error:

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error: metadata-generation-failed  × Encountered error while generating package metadata.

Please help, thank you!

Followed every walkthrough and still not working

Answer (score 21):

Pygame isn't updated for python 3.11, but you can still install a pre-version with `pip install pygame --pre`

Comment: # For Unix/ macOS:
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

# For windows:
py -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

Once you upgraded the build tools to the latest versions, try installing the package again and see if it works now.